# Typescript : Importing something that was exported with module.exports

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have the following theme file that for some reason needs to be written in ES5 :

```js
module.exports.theme = {
  primaryColor: 'blue',
  borderSize: '2px',
  // ...
}
```

I want to import it in a Typescript file (in a create-react-app environment). So I did the following :

```js
import { theme } from "../../../../session/theme";
```

Which causes the following error :

```
Attempted import error: 'theme' is not exported from '../../../../session/theme'.
```

I also tried exporting with `module.exports.default = { ... }` and importing the default, but it basically says the same thing (no default export).

How should I solve this ?

My `tsconfig.json` looks like this :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your module compiles with ES5 you have to use *require* instead of *import*.
Try this

```
const theme = require('../../../../session/theme').theme;
```

Otherwise you need to compile the module with ES6

Comment: By saying "compiles with ES5", do you mean "compiles to ES5" ?